# Software for organizing a "thing" gemach

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, tzedakah-charity

I'd like to organize a baby clothes [gemach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemach) in my area and I was wondering if there was any software that people have used to do this, or if this was a piece of software I'd have to write on my own.

### Requirements:

- If possible, I'd love this to be a "distributed gemach" where some donors might store their own donations.

  - This means these donors would have to post their own donations (logins, account management, etc).
  - This also means all donations would need a pickup address/time/maybe contact info once an item is "purchased".
- Aside from that, mostly just like an online store that allows for a finite set of tags/categories where the prices are $0 and there is no available shipping.  I just want to be able to skin it so it doesn't feel so e-commercey.

Comment: Great idea! If this doesn't exist yet, maybe someone will be inspired by this to create it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks.  If I become the one inspired, I'll let you know.

Comment: I am thinking about building web-based, distributed gemach software. I would appreciate your ideas about the must-have features.

Comment: @AlexGitlin I listed the must-have features I had in mind, above.  I have a bunch of other ideas on this, as well as a data-model and a just-barely-started Rails-on-Mongo project up on http://github.com/ckoppelman/distributed-gemach.  Get in touch with me there if you want to chat about this.

Comment: @Charles Koppelman This may not go down well. I am personally against the whole idea of 'gmach'. Open a second hand clothes store by all means but keep it as a business. If someone doesnt have money give it him free. But dont make it free for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use library software.

http://www.primasoft.com/pro_software/library_software_pro.htm